# The application or context root for this request has not been found

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I deployed movieapp-dailog(demo from ibm watson starter kit) in my bluemix account,

It giving me error **The application or context root for this request has not been found** when trying to access url **http://movieapp-dialog.au-syd.mybluemix.net/**

but the same application is working locally

Comment: Have you published/pushed it to Bluemix? Were there any errors? What is the Bluemix dashboard reporting for your app?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try: http://movieapp-dialog.au-syd.mybluemix.net/watson-movieapp-dialog/dist

You can find this information from "Deploying the app" step 8 in their git readme